# Error in import module in subpackage

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am having this package structure:

```
root/package/__init__.py
root/package/main.py
root/package/subpackage/__init__.py
root/package/subpackage/script1.py
root/package/subpackage/script2.py
```

Then in main.py I have `from package.subpackage import script1`

In script1 I have:

```
import script2

def do_smt(): 
    script2.do_smt()
```

So when I run `main.py` which invokes `script1.do_smt()`, I get an `ImportError` from script1 at the line `import script2`.

I have set my PYTHONPATH=..../root/

Do I miss out anything?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** 
When I tried the above setup in python 2, it works just fine. So this is a python3 related error. I am running python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 you can do

```
from .script2 import *                      #1
from package.subpackage.script2 import *    #2
from package.subpackage import script2      #3
from . import script2                       #4
```

relative imports seem to be required to be more specified.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't want to use relative import because I want to be able to run script1 as standalone script. I will go with relative import for now, and will have to run script1 as a module `python -m package.subpackage.script1`